# Android View Inflate Exception

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my project, I use an Activity called `PigeonSketch` and whenever I open the Activity it gives `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class <unknown>`

Here is my Activity class and XML layout file

```
public class PigeonSketch extends Activity {

    private RelativeLayout dashBoard;
    private ImageView imagePigeon;
    private Button search;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pigeon_sketch);
        setTitle("Pigeon")

        dashBoard = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pigeon_dashBoard);
        imagePigeon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pigeonsketch);
        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton)
    }
```

And the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".GridViewList" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pigeon_dashBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pigeonsketch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/image_pigeon"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/searchButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Search" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: remove setTitle("Pigeon") in your code

Comment: You define Button in xml and find using ImageButton in activity.

Comment: This is not related to the error. `search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.searchButton)` this must be `Button` as per the layout file and not `ImageButton`..

Comment: Mismatch there in xml file its `Button` and in java file there is `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

```
tools:context=".GridViewList"
```

to this

```
tools:context=".PigeonSketch"
```

or remove the line..

Comment: clean + build your project and then try to run it.

Comment: I found the problem is coming in <ImageView> part in XML layout file. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

First you are using wrong tools reference :

```
tools:context=".PigeonSketch"
```

Second you define Button in xml and find using ImageButton so replace ImageButton with Button in Activity :

```
private Button search;

search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton)
```

Comment: Have you check my ans ?